# Directory junction in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a hard-link with PHP. I know there are three kinds of links: Symlinks, hard-links,  and directory junctions (hard-links for directories).

In PHP a symlink is the `symlink()` function, a hard-link is `link()`, but what for a directory junction?

I need to use it for a web application, and a symlink is not enough for me.

Thanks

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: Currently I'm running the development server on Windows 7, but the production environment is Centos (Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory junctions are an NTFS-specific feature. There are no directory junctions in Linux. There are [directory-binding mounts](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) (look for "The bind mounts"), which provide similar functionality, however they require root access.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have root access to the production server. And regardless of this, I was asking how to create directory junctions with PHP, I don't really care if it is specific to Windows.

Comment: On windows, you will probably need to invoke an [external utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx). Still, this will not work once you move your code to your CentOS production server.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and as I was running specifically on Windows system, I did:

```
exec('mklink "' . $linkLocation . '" "' . $linkTarget . '" /J')
```

A successful result looked something like this:

```
Junction created for C:\...\... <<===>> C:\...\...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create hard links (or "directory junctions") to directories in Linux, it is not supported by the operating system. I don't know if it is possible using [link](http://php.net/link) in Windows but it should be as easy as trying.

Comment: From what I know I cannot use `link()` for directories.

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple function, it is working with windows.

```
<?php
function makeSymLink ($target, $link)
{
   exec('mklink /j "' . str_replace('/', '\\', $link) . '" "' .str_replace('/', '\\', $target) . '"');  
  }
?>
```